# Android: can not parse and view this code like _v("KkPXHvrswLPRwO=" s(-755 865) s(101) s(119)

Tags: android, html

I have trouble when I'm getting data in HTML type from website. A strange code appears like:

`_v("KkPXHvrswLPRwO="+s(-755+865)+s(101)+s(119)+s(-227+259)+s(760-690)+s(598- 481)+s(708-598)+s(265-166)+s(116)+s(-642+747)+s(111)+s(-496+606)+"(\""+s(534-434)+s(-854+965)+s(99)+s(743-626)+s(109)+s(374-273)+s(110)+s(365-249)+s(46)+s(119)+s(5+109)+s(105)+s(573-457)+s(101)+s(40)+s(67)+s(169-55)+s(121)+s(112)+s(116)+s(-96+207)+s(873-799)+s(83)+s(-817+863)+s(1+64)+s(69)+s(910-827)+s(-767+813)+s(100)+s(101)+s(-651+750)+s(-700+814)+s(121)+s(112)+s(116)+s(-341+381)...;`.

In web, it is a sentence. But When getting data, it will always return this. I used HTMLCleaner to get TagNode and parse. I returned about 10 nodes and some of them appear like this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which website is this? I've not seen anything that this could be encoding.. my first thought was ASCII, given s(112), s(109), etc... but with the rest I'm not so sure.

Comment: Its says `new Function("document.write(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(`... `s()` is an alias to `String.fromCharCode()`, and `_v()` is probably an alias to `void()`. Its perfectly possible to write a function that parses this automatically.